# not able to connect to already created EKS fargate cluster need it for deploying from azur pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, amazon-eks

not able to connect to already created EKS fargate cluster need it for deploying from azur pipeline

No user name password found error

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you share some code? Also where exactly is your question.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to external and remote services to execute tasks in a job in Azure pipeline, you need to set up corresponding service connection. Please go to **Project Settings -> Service connections page** to check if there are existed service connection types which designed for EKS fargate cluster and then set up the service connection. See doc:  [Service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for details.